# Is it possible to highlight "constants" in Python Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

It would be lovely if I could make constants look different in color (text or background). But I don't know how to do that. There is a setting, but it doesn't work for python. I know that there are technically no constants in python, but maybe it is possible to make that for upper case variables. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is an open feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26706

Comment: @JonSG that post was created 6 years ago… Maybe they are not planning to do that for some reasons